# "Positive" synonyms for 'problem' or 'worst'

Tags: word-usage

I need to find a positive synonym for 'problem' or 'worst' for some copy I am writing.  The context is that these are ratings for student performance in a tabular format (as in, "problem topics: lorem ipsum" or "worst topics: lorem ipsum"), and while I want to indicate that the topics I am describing need improvement, I don't want to sound overly negative.

There is a good chance that the students have had exposure to basic economic theory, so I am considering "marginal" (especially since the topics being described are being prioritized to maximize the marginal benefit of studying).  But this does not seem to be a standard usage.  In fact, outside of economics, marginal seems to indicate the opposite of what I'm looking for.

Any ideas?

Comment: You cannot find a positive synonym for negative words. I don't understand what you are looking for. Perhaps _poor_ or _imperfect_?

Comment: Do you mean "topics"? Or "areas"? "Topics" makes me think something along the lines of "topic for a paper." It's hard to tell if _lorem ipsum_ in your examples refers to behavioral problems or academic problems. If I'm catching your meaning, I'd be inclined to use something like, "Areas that could be improved: lorem ipsem."

Comment: @J.R. You are catching the meaning.  I am specifically tabulating "sub-subjects" in a large subject (mathematics) that the student needs improvement in.  So I would call that an "academic problem".  Sorry for the ambiguity.  I didn't notice it, since it isn't a problem in the domain I'm working in.

Comment: I would avoid marginal. In economics, the marginal value of something is the value of 1 more of that thing.

Comment: In economics, the marginal value of something is the derivative of the value with respect to the thing.  The usage is fine, at least in the contexts of economics and political science ("marginal voters" -- what we call swing votes).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're looking for *euphemisms*. The business world is prepared to support you! :-)

Traditional euphemisms for "problems" are "challenges" or "opportunities".

Euphemisms for "worst" could be "low-hanging fruit" or "easiest target" or even "top priority"

Comment: _Puzzle_ is another positive way to view problems, especially homework problems.

Comment: A professor in a compiler class included a set of optional features we could add to our compilers for extra credit. It was a list, and we could pick any, all, or none. He rated them "easy" "more challenging" and "most instructive."

Comment: Like code with the COME FROM command.

Comment: Terdon does not have the exposure to business language.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that you're looking for phrases that indicate change is needed, but have a neutral tone; you're trying to avoid sub-standard, mediocre, etc.

*Next steps* is a good fit to indicate that something needs work, but doesn't have an overtly negative connotation.

An equally bland phrase is *areas to focus on*.

This is my least favorite, but it might be what you're looking for. If you need three concise column headings, it's possible that: *excellent*, *good*, *other* might be okay.