# A Better Phrase for "On Hold" in the context of Stack Exchange

Tags: phrase-requests, rhetoric

I thought about the appropriate location for this question before posting, and I came to the conclusion that it is, at its root, a problem of diction and rhetoric... We would, certainly, like to *convince* question writers to edit their question, rather than to incite their frustration.

The [on hold] message became the norm for English-speaking Stack Exchange websites following [a movement to hurt people's feelings less with "close"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173497/every-close-has-its-thorn-replace-close-with-on-hold-for-the-first-five-d).

For a number of reasons brought up in the past and [the present](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/298683/should-we-change-on-hold-to-needs-revision-or-something-similar?cb=1), a suitable alternative may be in order.

What is an alternative that

- is succinct
- conveys a need for revision
- is sufficiently passive (and thus minimizes anger)
- (preferably) conveys a sense of limited time

and, most importantly, **is clear to most readers**?

NOTE: This is an English question. Not meta. That said, off-topic is a possibility. *That said*, I don't think `on hold` brings any clarity to off-topic in the slightest.

Comment: Awaiting Revision?

Comment: @Jeff, that is good...but I would like something with a sense of slight urgency. (I added a bullet above.)

Comment: Urgently Awaiting Revision?

Comment: Needs Revision?

Comment: Isn't this meta?  HOLD IT NOW! (Joking, mostly.)

Comment: *Can not be answered unless revised within five days* Is a little verbose, but tells what needs to be done, why, and when. A countdown with a resolution of days wouldn't be too fiddly, would it? (*within four days, within three days*...)

Comment: I'm sorry, but you seem to be ignoring the fact that many "on hold" questions are actually off-topic, so you need to add that potential meaning to your list... None of the recommended phrases allow for this definition. Regardless, this is a question better suited to [Meta Stack Exchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com/), as it's the only place actual changes to the SE world would be considered.

Comment: [This answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/128572/positive-synonyms-for-problem-or-worst/128579#128579) to a somewhat related question suggests “Next Step(s)” (which could even work with “off-topic”/fatal holds) and in so doing mentions “Needs work” (which would not work with “off-topics”).

Comment: @Catija You are correct. I would like to see a question referencing this question on `Meta`, however, in the spirit of *exchanging* between our many "stacks", I thought it proper to consult the English specialists.

Comment: @ZX9 I think you need to spend a bit of time learning how SE works before you start trying to come up with alternative terminology.

Comment: How about "In the penalty box"?

Comment: The ultimate irony... It's been placed `on hold`... If you believe it's more appropriate, perhaps a kind moderator would migrate this to meta?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What about **needs improvement** or something along those lines.  Variants like *needs to be improved* could be considered too, but the key concept is that the question is not ready yet, but can be changed so it is ready.

Comment: On ELU, it should of course be ***needs improved***.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: Really?  'Needs to be improved' perhaps, but not something as ungrammatical as 'needs improved'.

Comment: There have been several questions on here about the dialectal feature _needs/wants X’ed_ (it's quite grammatical in some US dialects); that's what I was referencing, jokingly.

Comment: It's good but 2½ times as long as "on hold".

Comment: @Avon Whatever advantages the replacement for "on hold" may have, it is unlikely to be shorter.

Comment: @GetzelR Indeed. We're not going to get it that short. But screen width is at a premium in these days of mobile internet. Just a few characters can make a big difference. Nevertheless I have upvoted this let it be known.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: Sorry for not being enough of a regular here to have picked up the jocular intent behind your tongue-in-cheek suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest **needs fixing**

Certainly succinct
I think it conveys a need for revision
I think it's about as passive as it can be within the bounds of the other requirements. It's not accusatory at any rate.
I think it conveys a sense of limited time.

Comment: `Fixing` implies it's broken in the first place. That might be true, but the whole point of this is not to antagonize the asker. The implication should just be improvement on the current post.

Comment: @TusharRaj I agree "improvement" is better in that respect but I think it's too long. Short synonym for "improvement" anyone? I don't think there is one. I don't think "fixing" is particularly antagonizing.

Comment: You gotta look at it from the perspective of the askers. `Closed`, which is neutral in tone, was done away with because it's hurtful. You really think `fixing` would fare better?

Comment: @TusharRaj "Closed" was rejected for different reasons to that: To quote the article linked to in the OP: "The word "closed" sounds final" That was the problem with it. Not that it was antagonizing - it was off-putting.

Comment: I didn't say 'closed' was anatagonizing. I said it was neutral and still deemed hurtful. `Closed` implies it's rejected. `Fixing` implies  it's broken. Not better. You were on the right track with a shorter synonym of improvement. (PS - Use backticks in the comments for code formatting)

Comment: @TusharRaj But it is a different reason why it was off-putting: people read `closed` as `final - nothing I can do about it`. `Needs fixing` doesn't suffer from *that*. `on hold` suffers a little from that: it doesn't really communicate that it can be put right. I agree that mine sounds more critical than `needs improvement` but I really don't think to the point of being antagonizing like `rejected` would be. `needs improvement` is also quite critical. Anyone of a sensitive disposition is going to take that to heart too. (Of course, all just my opinion.) Thanks for the backtick tip btw.

Comment: I get your point now. It's better than I thought, though still not perfect. Upvoted.

Comment: @TusharRaj Thanks for the +1. I'm well accustomed to not being in tune with other people's value judgements on things like this. I agree it's not perfect. The irony of this question is it should really be closed as a matter of opinion.

Comment: @Avon, I agree with you (upvoted), but isn't most of ELU subject to some opinion? (...aside from some obvious grammatical tenets.)

Comment: @ZX9 Indeed much of ELU is like that. I have seen votes to close for that reason but really being a matter of opinion doesn't actually make it inappropriate in and of itself. Honestly, I think it's borderline but, because the question and the answers have had up-votes (and particularly because _I_ have answered it), I don't think there would be any case for closing it or any danger of anyone trying.

Comment: @Avon, what did I do wrong? Less than 24 hours and it's `[on hold]`...

Comment: @ZX9 I think if it was a hypothetical question about a hypothetical website (not SE) then it would belong better here. The belonging better on meta is the main issue.

Comment: @Avon that makes sense. thanks! (...they still didn't move it.)

Answer (score 2):

**Pending review** - universally recognized and inoffensive
**cutoff UFN** - acronym for *until further notice*
**on ice** - *(fig.)* short for *suspended temporarily*

Comment: The first two make it feel like the owner of the question don't need to take action. I like `on ice`, though...

Comment: I like "*pending review*", but it's very slightly imprecise: the question has already been reviewed, and now it's *pending revision*. +1 either way. The problem I have with most answers on this page is they don't make clear that it's *primarily the OP's responsibility* to make the needed changes; I know we want to encourage the community as a whole to dive in and fix problematic questions, but that absolves OP of too much of his obligation to fix *his own question*, IMO.

Comment: @DanBron What would you suggest? `Please Revise`?

Comment: I'd suggest *pending revision* over *pending review* in the first place. But I don't know what to suggest to signal to OP that it is *primarily his mess, and no-one else's* to clean up. If I can think of something, I'll let you know.

Answer (score -1):

How about something like **' (in) redraft(ing) phase'**

The `redraft` says that the question needs to be edited/corrected/expanded to be on topic.

The `phase` says that it's a phase that will end at some point (after which the question will be closed). I can't think of any shorter way to denote urgency.

Comment: A bit 'obscure' , I don't think it immediately conveys what the issue is with the question.

Comment: @Josh61: Well, I gave it a shot :)

Comment: Other users may like it, just my personal view.